# Uplod images to azure blob storage - Works locally, fails when deployed

Tags: c#, azure, aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASPNetBoilerplate as a base framework, using the .Net Core template, and I am trying to upload photos to a blob storage.
 The site is hosted in an Azure Web App, and the Blob storage is in the same subscription.

I am using the below code, When I run it locally in debug mode, it works, but as soon as I deploy it to Azure, I get an error of unable to locate the file D:\public\images\

Can anyone see what I have done incorrectly for the azure deployment, or why it would work locally but not in Azure.

I am trying to generate the uploaded file name from a guid, upload the image(s) to azure, and store the generated filename into an sql database.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

```
 public async Task<ICollection<BlogImage>> UploadFileAsync(ICollection<IFormFile> files, string RecordType,  int id) {
        ICollection<BlogImage> _blogImages = new Collection<BlogImage>();


         string imageFullPath = null;
        if (files == null || files.Count == 0)
        {
             await Task.FromException(new Exception("No File Supplied"));
        }
        try
        {
            //Connect To Azure
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = GetAuth();

            //Create a refernce to blob client
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            //Create a reference to the container
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("images");

            if (await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
            {
                await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(
                    new BlobContainerPermissions
                    {
                        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                    }
                );
            }

            foreach (var file in files)
            {

                string imageName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(RecordType + "/" +id.ToString() + "/" + imageName);
                cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = file.ContentType;

                // Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(file)
                Logger.Info("file name is: " + file.FileName + " Name is: " + file.Name + " Generated Name is: " + imageName);
                using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(file.FileName))
                {
                    Logger.Info("File Opened;");

                    // Upload the file
                    await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
                    System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fileStream);

                    var im = new BlogImage { ImageName = imageName, Size = file.Length, ContentType = file.ContentType, Height = image.Height, Width = image.Width };
                    fileStream.Dispose();
                    _Images.Add(im);
                }

                imageFullPath = cloudBlockBlob.Uri.ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Exception triggered: " + ex.Message);
            _telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
        }
        return _Images;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `File.OpenRead` method to read the file stream which takes a path (which probably don't exists - depends on the Azure Service you are using to host the App). However, you should probably use the `OpenReadStream()` for the passed `IFormFile` to get the stream instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your app is now deployed on cloud and the path is not configured properly. You can try below steps-

- Go to your resources under your subscription and select the app service under which you deployed your app.
  [image]
- Under Development Tools, select Advanced Tools and click Go. This will take you to the pseudo hard drive where your app is deployed.

[image]

- Under Debug console, select CMD.

[image]

- It will look something like below. Create/put your file in the appropriate path and use that path.

[image]